# How to concatenate 2 values in mule?

Tags: mule

Can someone please let me know how to concatenate multiple values in mule?

Something like,

```
#[payload.getPayload()].concat(#[getSubject()])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you are using Mule 3.3.x or above. If so you can use Mule Expression Language(MEL).

One example using MEL is:

```
#['Hello' + 'World']
```

Or MEL also allows you to use standard Java method invocation:

```
#[message.payload.concat(' Another String')]
```

[Cheat sheet on MEL](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/refcard-mel.pdf)

**MULE 4 Update**

For Mule 4. Dataweave 2.0 is the main expression language:

Simple concat:

```
#['Hello' ++ ' World']
```

Comment: Is it possible to do #['Hello'] + #['World'] or #[message.payload.concat(#['World'])

Comment: You don't need the nested expression: #[]. You can access multiple values from a single MEL expression. For example if you want to concatentate a messgae property with the payload you can use:#[message.payload.concat(message.inboundProperties['http.method'])] or similar for different parts of the payload etc. You can use the #[string:] evaluator to use nested expressions but that works differently and the best practice is to use MEL.

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative is to use **Mule Design** plugin :

Drop an **"Append String" operation** as many times as you need.

This operation takes the message payload of the previous step and concats a specified string to it.
Not sure about performance details, but it will be surely more easy to maintain.

[Append to String - MuleSoft](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.2/append-string-transformer-reference)

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a string buffer using expression component

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[StringBuffer sb = new 
    StringBuffer();
    flowVars.stBuffer=sb;
    ]]></expression-component>
```

and then append use append on string buffer any where in the flow.

flowVars.stBuffer.append("string to append")

Once done use `#[flowVars.stBuffer]` to access the concatenated string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add two different values received through payload in the mule flow then we can use concat() method.

For example below we have received values through arraylist where i am adding two diffrent fields i.e. FirstName and the LastName -

concat(#[payload[0].'firstname']," " #[payload[0].'lastname']